# Find the min Facebook Hacker cup 2013

Tags: algorithm

Since the contest is now over I would like to ask about this question. I've been really struggling with this question for the past three days because actually I'm not able to understand it.

**Here's the question:**
[Find the min Facebook Hacker Cup 2013](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zupdZnkQ)

**Here's the site where I found a solution for this question:**
[Solutions](http://notes.tweakblogs.net/blog/8648/facebook-hacker-cup-2013-qualification-round-problem-analysis.html)

**What I'm not able to understand is the following part:**

> Although these first K values could be anything, we can make some useful observations
> about the contents of the array after the initial K elements:
>
> 1. Every element will be between 0 and K (inclusive) by the pigeonhole principle.
> 2. Consequently, every window of K + 1 consecutive elements will contain each value between 0 and K exactly once (i.e. it contains a permutation of the integers 0 through K).
> 3. Consequently, for i > 2K: M[i] = M[i - (K + 1)].

Though I'm able to understand the second and third points iff the first is true. The first one is actually troubling me. Why do the elements have to be between 0 and K why can't all of them just be the minimum non-negative integer which is not present in the initial K elements.

For eg:
For  the following test case:

> 1
>
> 46 18
>
> 7 11 9 46

The first K elements are:

> [7, 40, 35, 26, 19, 34, 15, 36, 37, 2, 31, 28, 41, 0, 9, 16, 1, 20]

Now why do the rest of the elements have to be between 0 and 18, when I have elements which are more than 18 in my previous K elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you have K numbers `{a0,a1,a2...a(k-1)}`, now you want to find the first non-negative number that is not among them. Can it be more than `K`? Well if that is true, then all the numbers `{0,1,...K}` are present in the above set and that is `K+1` numbers should be present in the above set, which consists of `K` numbers. This is not possible and hense a contradiction with the assumption that the new number is more than `K`. So on each step the next number you add will be in the range `[0,K]` and thus on the `K+1` step all the last `K+1` numbers will be in that step and thus be different numbers in that range.

Comment: I've edited the question to make myself more clear

Comment: @KartikAnand I believe I understand what you ask for and also I believe I answered this question in my answer. Do an induction and prove for each consequent element that it is in the range `[0,K]` using the proof I do.

Comment: But see, since the least element that is not in the previous K is 3, so I'll append 3 then 4, 5, 6, 8 etc till 18. Then why can't I fill 21? Why should the array start repeating now

Comment: well not quite true, after 12 you will fill in 2 as the two that is present in the array above will be "free". And also 5 numbers after that the 0 will be free, so you will fill in 0.

Comment: I guess now I'm getting on your nerves, sorry for that. But what do you specifically mean by "free" ??

Comment: Try to write the numbers one by one in the sequence. By "free" I mean 2 will no longer be in the last `K` numbers after adding 10 numbers `{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}`, so after adding those, the last `K` will be `{31, 28, 41, 0, 9, 16, 1, 20, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}` and note **two is not in them**. So on the next iteration you add 2 instead of the 13 you expect.

Comment: Ok now i understand, actually I was not understanding the question well enough, I wasn't shifting the last K values and that's why I was getting confused. Thank you very much.